# How filtering two distinct lists synchronously by a node attribute in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The result of a more complex Cypher query is a list of nodes and a list of relationships, where each position/ row of one list is content-wise related to the same position/ row of the other list. The relationship consists exclusively of the position in the two lists, there is no graph between the according elements.

[image: List]

Because I need to filter both lists by an attribute of the nodes, I combined both lists in a map and tried to realize my intention by [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension).

```
MATCH
  <complex query>
WITH collect(labelA) AS nodesList, collect(relation) AS relationList
WITH {nodes:nodesList, relations:relationList} AS data
WITH [x IN data WHERE x.nodes.attributName <> „text“] AS filteredData
RETURN filteredData;
```

Which understandably leads to the following error in line 5.

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Type mismatch: expected a map but was List{(4538063), (4538063), (4538063)}

When I unwind the `x.nodes` part in a line before it works from a technical point of view, but I’m loosing my dependencies to the second table. 
So how can I filter both lists synchronously by a node attribute of the first list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of pairs, so you should collect them as such and then filter them as a single item.

Example of what I mean...

```
MATCH
  <complex query>
WITH COLLECT({node:labelA, relation:relation}) AS data
// or you can do
// WITH COLLECT([labelA, relation]) AS data
WITH filter(x IN data WHERE x.node.attributName <> "text") AS filteredData
RETURN filteredData;
```